# Dynamically added controls missing during GridView RowUpdating

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with a TemplateField column that I put PlaceHolder controls in.  During the DataBound event for the GridView I dynamically add a few CheckBoxes to the PlaceHolder.  That works fine and displays as expected.

My problem is that during the RowUpdating event the PlaceHolder contains no controls; my CheckBoxes are missing.  I also noticed that they're missing during the RowEditing event.

I want to be able to get the values of the CheckBoxes during the RowUpdating event so I can save them to the database.

Here's some example code.  I've trimmed out a lot to reduce size, but if you want to see specifics just ask and I'll be happy to add more.

HTML:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    ondatabound="gridView_DataBound" onrowupdating="gridView_RowUpdating" 
    onrowediting="gridView_RowEditing" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Countries">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="countriesPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="countriesPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="editButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="updateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind:

```
// This method works fine, no obvious problems here.
protected void gridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Loop through the Holidays that are bound to the GridView
    var holidays = (IEnumerable<Holiday>)gridView.DataSource;
    for (int i = 0; i < holidays.Count(); i++)
    {
        // Get the row the Holiday is bound to
        GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[i];
        // Get the PlaceHolder control
        var placeHolder = (PlaceHolder)row.FindControl("countriesPlaceHolder");
        // Create a CheckBox for each country and add it to the PlaceHolder
        foreach (Country country in this.Countries)
        {
            bool isChecked = holidays.ElementAt(i).Countries.Any(item => item.ID == country.ID);
            var countryCheckBox = new CheckBox
            {
                Checked = isChecked,
                ID = country.Abbreviation + "CheckBox",
                Text = country.Abbreviation
            };
            placeHolder.Controls.Add(countryCheckBox);
        }
    }
}

protected void gridView_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    // EXAMPLE: I'm expecting checkBoxControls to contain my CheckBoxes, but it's empty.
    var checkBoxControls = gridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("countriesPlaceHolder").Controls;

    gridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}

protected void gridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // EXAMPLE: I'm expecting checkBoxControls to contain my CheckBoxes, but it's empty.
    var checkBoxControls = ((PlaceHolder)gridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("countriesPlaceHolder")).Controls;

    // This is where I'd grab the values from the controls, create an entity, and save the entity to the database.

    gridView.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}
```

This is the article that I followed for my data binding approach: http://www.aarongoldenthal.com/post/2009/04/19/Manually-Databinding-a-GridView.aspx

Comment: are you casting the place holder variable properly for example  PlaceHolder placeHolder = e.Row.FindControl("countriesPlaceHolder") as PlaceHolder;
you also need to check the RowType if( if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)  then put your code for PlaceHolder instance after that.. try that..

Comment: Yeah, in my actual code I do cast it to a PlaceHolder.  I also perform a check on the RowType as you suggested.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I can't see where you are checking the RowType..

Comment: Check this answer on StackOverflow as well and see if it will help sounds like same issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343943/adding-controls-in-gridview-dynamically

Comment: Sorry, I meant my actual code as opposed to the sample code I posted above.  However, I just updated the sample code's `gridView_RowUpdating` and even tested it on my end, but no luck yet.  I also checked out the link, but that doesn't seem to be my problem.  I am dealing with the correct row; I've verified that while debugging.

Comment: I just realized that I wasn't supposed to add that check to the RowUpdating method.  However, your link is doing binding in the RowDataBound event, but I'm using DataBound.  I don't need to worry about the header or invalid rows with the approach I took.  And the binding does work fine.  I'm able to see my CheckBoxes with the correct Checked state.  It's only in the RowUpdating event handler that I'm not able to see what I expect.

Comment: I've seen the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle link, but I'm not sure I understand it well.  I saw the note for the DataBound event that says "Use this event to format data-bound content or to initiate data binding in other controls that depend on values from the current control's content."  I took that to mean that I should be adding my CheckBoxes during the DataBound event, since they're dependent on the content for that row.  Did I misunderstand?

Comment: when you call BindData() shouldn't you be binding the DataGrid..?

Comment: Yes, I do set the `DataSource` of my `GridView` and call `DataBind()` inside the `BindData` method.  I just left that code out above to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call your BindData() method on page load.

"Dynamic controls or columns need to be recreated on every page load, because of the way that controls work. Dynamic controls do not get retained so you have to reload them on every page postback; however, viewstate will be retained for these controls."

See [Cells in gridview lose controls on RowUpdating event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012134/cells-in-gridview-lose-controls-on-rowupdating-event)

Also in the article you linked, there is an ItemTemplate and an EditItemTemplace because they have different displays, i.e. read only and editable. Yours are the same so I think you could simplify your design:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" ondatabound="gridView_DataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Countries">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="countriesPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="editButton" runat="server" Text="Edit" onclick="editButton_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="updateButton" runat="server" Text="Update" onclick="updateButton_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void gridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Loop through the Holidays that are bound to the GridView
        var holidays = (IEnumerable<Holiday>)gridView.DataSource;
        for (int i = 0; i < holidays.Count(); i++)
        {
            // Get the row the Holiday is bound to
            GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[i];
            // Get the PlaceHolder control
            var placeHolder = (PlaceHolder) row.FindControl("countriesPlaceHolder");
            var countryCheckBox = new CheckBox
                                      {
                                          Checked = true,
                                          ID = "auCheckBox",
                                          Text = "Aus",
                                          Enabled = false
                                      };
            placeHolder.Controls.Add(countryCheckBox);

            var editButton = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("editButton");
            editButton.CommandArgument = i.ToString();
            var updateButton = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("updateButton");
            updateButton.CommandArgument = i.ToString();
            updateButton.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton editButton = (LinkButton) sender;
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(editButton.CommandArgument);

        GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[index];
        // Get the PlaceHolder control
        LinkButton updateButton = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("updateButton");
        updateButton.Visible = true;
        editButton.Visible = false;

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("auCheckBox");
        if (checkbox != null)
        {
            checkbox.Enabled = true;
            // Get value and update
        }
    }

    protected void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton updateButton = (LinkButton)sender;
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(updateButton.CommandArgument);

        GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[index];
        // Get the PlaceHolder control
        LinkButton editButton = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("updateButton");
        editButton.Visible = true;
        updateButton.Visible = false;

        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("auCheckBox");
        if (checkbox != null)
        {
            // Get value and update

            checkbox.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

If you want to be it enabled from the get go, just remove the enabled checks and you can delete your edit button.

Hope that helps.

Comment: At first I thought I was calling `BindData()` during page load, but then I realized I was only calling it during non-postbacks.  I tweaked the logic to only call `BindData()` on non-postbacks, but call my code that adds the dynamic CheckBoxes on every load.  That did the trick!  Thanks!